# Wordpress SEO for google search reasult

Tags: wordpress, seo

I am using wordpress yoast seo plugin and trying to create  similar like this
google serach result, what should i do for this

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1322528/5746372fa3932e7e9f86203072707b96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log into Google Webmaster Tools

> https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Search Appearance > Sitelinks

> https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334

Comment: All webmaster tools allows you to do is demote Sitelinks. You cannot specify Sitelinks to use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're after `Site Links` (the links that appear towards the bottom of the Google snippet). Unfortunately, this is out of your control as they are completely automated:

> At the moment, sitelinks are automated. We're always working to improve our sitelinks algorithms, and we may incorporate webmaster input in the future. There are best practices you can follow, however, to improve the quality of your sitelinks. For example, for your site's internal links, make sure you use anchor text and alt text that's informative, compact, and avoids repetition.

Read up on how you should be marking up your content to make sure you're giving yourself the best opportunity.